# Looking to add the 220v outlet in the garage - possible no fuse box in the garage?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, garage

I live in a condo (built in 1983) with only 3 apartments in the building, and I am the only one with a garage in the building. I am planning to add the 220v outlet in the garage (will hire an electrician) and want to identify the fuse box first. But I can't locate anything look like a fuse box except the image shown.
Is it possible that there is no fuse box in the garage even though there are already some 110v outlets? If so, is it still possible to add 220v outlets?

[image]

Comment: That's not it. That's telephone wiring.

Comment: Yeah, can you find a breaker or breakers next to where the electric meter for your condo is?

Comment: Ask the electrician for a quote, you will then know for sure.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica   YEAH, YIKES.  but let's just run some 240 thru there, I'm sure it'll be fine.  NOT NOT NOT!

Comment: A multi family dwelling may require a licensed electrician I know you said you were going to hire one. A good starting point is at the power meter location. Service panels are usually located on the same wall that the power enters the building.